# EF model property not null without [Required]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to have Entity framework generate a table, from a model, with the column marked as not null without using the `[Required]` annotation on the model's property?

Reason:

The object is posted to an api and I check `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller. The property is supposed to be generated server side and not come from outside, but if I have the property `[Required]` the `ModelState.IsValid` is false (in which case I return with a `BadRequest(ModelState);`).

Can I tell EF to make the column not null in some other way?

I guess another solution would be to expect another object(some sort of DTO) to be sent to the api and then do a mapping. But that object would look exactly the same save for this single property, which makes it seem a bit unnecessary, right?

Comment: Take a look at ModelBuilder/Fluent API, instead of using data annotations you can use ModelBuilder to define these attributes

Comment: Don't accept the entity directly. You're just asking for trouble by doing that. Use another class and map the values over to an instance of your entity class from that.

Comment: Yeah! Really helpful! Not sure if I'll do the dto + mapping. I will try and see if it feels good. Fluent api I'll probably use anyway! Thanks!

Comment: Not only possible. You should! Models should be POCO with no dependencies and no attributes (if you can avoid it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`IsRequired`](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/isrequired-method) method in your `DbContext` class like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(t => t.YourProperty).IsRequired();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I would not use Entity Framework's entities directly, I would use a DTO first and map it into a EF Entity, why? Because your DTO and EF Entity have not the same responsibility.

DTO :  Data transfer object, so just use it to transfer data
EF Entity :  it's the model binding to your database.

Comment: DTO is public Data model for your API and visible by API clients. DB models are private and used internally in your system, including in your DB.